# How to display the nested foreach values in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I need to display the nested for-each loop values in smarty.

```
I have the array like


Array ( 
     [err] => 0 
     [code] => 0 
     [msg] => Success 
     [retval] => Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 8 
              [thread_id] => 8 
              [body] => Hi test message 
              [priority] => 1 
              [sender_id] => 11 
              [cdate] => 2015-06-01 12:26:55 
              [status] => 1 
              [subject] => Hi 
              [user_name] => soniya kaliappan 
         ) 
     ) 
)
```

how can I get the  retval['body'] value in smarty . Please help me .

Comment: {foreach from=$mge_user item="value"}
     {$value}
     <ul>
     {foreach from=$value.retval key=key2 item="value2"}
     <li>{$value2.body}</li>
     {/foreach}
</ul> {/foreach}

Comment: Please include it in your question instead of the comments, it's virtually unreadable in the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run the `foreach` inside another `foreach` -

```
{foreach from=$yourarray item=loopVal}
  {foreach from=$loopVal.retval key=retval item=retVal}
    {$retVal.body}
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Or there will be only one array inside `retval` then -

```
{foreach from=$yourarray item=loopVal}
    {$loopVal.retVal.0.body}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Error: Illegal string offset 'retval'